# How to check if value is string in lua?

Tags: lua

Hello guys i please need your help.
I have values, most of them are numbers but some of them are strings.
How can i check if value is string or number?

I already tried this code but when it reach string value i get error " attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'numberValue' (a nil value)"

```
function Config:IsNumber(value)
    if value ~=nill or value ~=nil then                 
        local numberValue = tonumber(value)
        if numberValue/numberValue ==1 then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end
end
end
```

Comment: there is a function in lua called `type`, you can use it like `type(value) == "number"` and this will only be true if `value` is a number.

Comment: Thats good to know, thanks however i found out that all my values are strings but some of theme are numbers what can be "tonumber" and some of them are just chars.

Comment: I found solution  strmatch(val,"%d")   , thanks for help anyway

Comment: if this solved your problem you should not be asking "how to check wether a value is a string" as you obviously wanted to know wether a string contains a digit. if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let's start with errors in your code.

- You have 2 `end`s to many.
- it is `nil`, not `nill`. I'm not sure where you're going with that check.

Other issues / things to improve:

`numberValue / numberValue == 1` does not make any sense. A number divided by itself always results in `1`. So checking that is pointless.

Also instead of

```
if something == 1 then
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

Can simply be replaced by `return something == 1`. There is no need for a conditional statement here.

To your question:

To check wether a value is a string use `type(value) == "string"`.

To check wether a value can be converted to a number use `tonumber(value)`. It will either return a number or nil.

So according to your error the conversion to a number failed.

If you don't know for sure that your value can be converted to a number, you should ensure that `tonumber` succeeded before you do any operations on its return value.

```
local numberValue = tonumber(value)
if not numberValue then
  print("converting value to a number failed")
  return
end
-- at this point you know numberValue is a number
```

So if you wanted to write a function that ensures a string represents a number you could do something like this:

```
function IsNumber(value)
  return tonumber(value) and true or false
end
```

Comment: As i wrote before this solved  my problem  strmatch(val,"%d") ,I needed to check if value in string are digits.Those 2 nills checks are there because api sometimes return "nill" and sometimes "nil" and conditional statement is there because i want my method return true or false and not number.My problem is solved ty anyway.

Comment: you don't get my point. somenumber == 1 resolves to true or false. not a number. so you're basically using a conditional statement to convert true to true and false to false.